# I can't select query tables in mysql, but only with certain names

Tags: mysql, web.py

I have a couple tables in a database named `19efdf22eeefaa6dc322be094bb2da475d4d457c` and `8e0b5a906b375bc5f6c44ca4274d7374ea43435a`.

When I run the code

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
ORDER BY name ASC
```

Where `table_name` is one of the above tables, the query fails on the second one but not the first one and I am not sure why.

This seems to happen randomly and I found that if I surround the table names with "`" (the grave mark), then it works just fine, but I am using web.py for my web framework and there is some useful wrappers for easy queries involving insert and select.

I am generating these string using a Python hash function but they are all pretty much the same (not the same, per say, but all similar).

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @hexist I am getting the error `1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '8e0b5a906b375bc5f6c44ca4274d7374ea43435a ORDER BY name ASC' at line 1"`. I know this is because of the lack of back-quotes, but if I can use the handy functions instead of writing full fledged queries, I would like to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure either but you should put backquotes around every identifier like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table_name`
ORDER BY `name` ASC
```

MySQL understands the backquote around database name, table name, and column name in this way. Here is an old URL how what you did is indeed recommended : http://mail.python.org/pipermail/db-sig/2007-August/005172.html

You could just insert before and after `\x60` (the backquote) to the table name. Forgive me, I am not conversant in Python.

## UPDATE 2013-05-20 22:08 EDT

Here is my conjecture: The first two characters, if taken to be a hexadecimal value, is less than 128 and I think the character set for information_schema.tables may be interfering with the table name's interpretation. You will have to experiment with table names where the first two characters are less or equal to  `7F`. The only way to know if this is case is to add Python code that retries the SHA1 hash again if the first two characters (in terms of hexadecimal value) is greater than `7F`.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: @DrewPierce According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html, backquotes can used around any identifier as long as the identifier is not greater than 64 characters.

Comment: point being name appears not to be reserved. plus they are ugly and stress out the pinky !

Comment: Yeah. I know that the back-quotes make it so mysql sees them as identifiers as table, columns, etc. But the two table names are obviously not reserved names, so I am wondering why mysql fails on the second one and not the first one.

Comment: Is it the same code that generates the creation of the table in both instances? Is the code with `SELECT` query that fails for one and succeeds for the other called from the same place?

Comment: Yeah, it's a function in python that I am using, so the same exact code is ran each time.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Wow. Well I am currently not at my computer, so I can't try it. But that sounds right to me! It would make my life so much easier to use the wrapper functions. I will upvote for now, and then accept it if it works! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

in MySQL, tables with names starting with a digit 0-9 can only be accessed with backticks.

I suggest a simple fix - prepend table names with "_" 
.